# Question about orthogonal/orthonormal functions and how to find an orthonormal set.

Tags: functions, orthogonality, orthonormal

Given an orthogonal set of functions, how can you find an orthonormal set? I understand that you'd have to divide it by the norm of the function, but I'm not sure how to get the norm to be honest.

If I'm given the set $\{\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) \}$ or $\{\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) \}$, how would I find the corresponding *orthonormal* set of functions?

Could anyone give me a good starting point, or point me to a resource that'll explain how this works?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Can someone check if I am doing this correct??

With the limits $-L$ to $L$, I integrate the following:
$$\int_{-L}^{L} \sin^2\bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\bigg)dx$$
and get the norm as $$\sqrt{L - \frac{\sin(2n\pi)L}{2n\pi}}$$

So my orthonormal set will be
$$\bigg\{\frac{\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})}{\sqrt{L - \frac{\sin(2n\pi)L}{2n\pi}}} \bigg\} $$

I feel like it doesn't seem right, could anyone let me know if I'm making any mistakes?

Comment: Note that the norm is given by the sqaure root of the inner product. All we have to do is divide each term by the square root of the norm to make it into a orthonormal set.

Comment: @sein If I'm taking the inner product of either of the functions that I have above, how would I know what limits to use? Should I do $-L$ to $L$, or $-\infty$ to $\infty$? Or something else?

Comment: This looks like $-L$ to $L$

Comment: @Andrei Oh I seee, thank! Is there any way we can know though? If maybe I was given any other functions, then in that case, how would I know what to use as the limits?

Comment: @Applesauce44 they should be given to you when the norm is defined. If none is given I presume you can select one of your choice.

Comment: @CyclotomicField ahh okay, understood. Thanks!